# How to resolve junit library in jMonkeyEngine3 project

Tags: jmonkeyengine

I am new to JMonkeyEngine. I have downloaded and installed jMonkeyEngine3 SDK, and trying to make the Hello Sample Application but it always shows a dialog that says:

> JUnit library has not been downloaded

I have tried using Resolve Reference Problems and using Ant Library Manager but here I am not getting any single option for the JUnit library, please tell me how can I resolve this problem, thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

I suffered the same problem , just Right click the project -> properties -> Libraries -> Compile Tests and remove the junit libs there ...

Answer (score 0):

Go to Help > Check for Latest Updates, Add junit Plugins